# Is there a way to set default compatibility level for Confluent Schema Registry?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

We are planning to use the Confluent Schema Registry within our Kafka ecosystem. We use the schema registry image from Confluent and run it within our Kubernetes platform. The default compatibility level is set as `BACKWARDS`, however, we would want to set it as `FORWARD_TRANSITIVE` as soon as the schema registry starts.

I know this can be achieved by making a [REST API call to update the global compatibility level](https://docs.confluent.io/cloud/current/sr/sr-rest-apis.html#update-the-global-compatibility-level), but is there any environment variable that can do this, without making the REST API call?

Thanks.

Comment: Your link is for hosted Schema Registry, not self installed

Answer (score 1):

You'd set `schema.compatibility.level` config, yes

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/installation/config.html#schema-compatibility-level

This can be set in a Kubernetes manifest or as an env-var directly

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/docker/config-reference.html#sr-long-configuration